# Mifare Desfire EV1 : Understand the authenfication process commands

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare

i'm new to Mifare Desfire Cards. My goal is to create a file with data in this Mifare Card. First, i'm just having troubles with authentification process : 
1. I sent the command 0x0A | 0x00 to the PICC and the PICC returned a frame with : 0xAF | 8 bytes word (probably random encyphered number B) but after this, I dont understand what I am supposed to do with encryption mecanisms..., what is the next step ? I mean what is the next command I have to send ?

Answer (score 0):

MIFARE DESFire EV1 uses [3-pass mutual authentication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-pass_protocol) for the authentication.

You can refer [this](https://www.mifare.net/support/forum/topic/mifare-desfire-authentication/) for reference.

If you don't wanna smash your head and don't want to get into low level implementation, NXP already provides an Open API [TapLinx](https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/taplinx/), which you can simply integrate in your project and make use of all the features just by invoking APIs

eg: `desfireObject.authenticate(key);`